# Need help for migrating OsCommerce database it Magento database

Tags: database, magento, migration, oscommerce

I need to migrate OsCommerce database to Magento database. I found a tool on the Magento site but it does not work for me. :( Can somebody help me with that task?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to import **Products**, but not **Customers**

I always tell my clients that they need to start from a new number for all new Customers as there are much more information in Magento and the "conversion" is not suitable, and they always have the customer information with all sales in their ERP system, so they will never lose anything that special, only that the new customer needs to create a new account again, witch that as well, can be easily managed by sending a newsletter to all customers explaining that they will have a much better service with the new system.

To have the products imported sucessfully, do this:

- Create manually all attributes in Magento for the products you need to use
- Create 1 product manually with all information you have
- Go to import/export and **export the CSV file** with that one and only product
- Analyse the CSV file and in OSCommerce, export the same data into a new CSV file
- **Import the CSV** from OSCommerce into Magento using the import tool.

you will have to upload the product images manually by FTP and all will work fine.